# action script 3 Bulkloader class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

Is there any swc or Class for loading lots of assets images,videos etc in flash which we can use later in project ?

I found one https://github.com/arthur-debert/BulkLoader but this does not work with Flex.
Is there any alternative that can work with flex too ?

Comment: Given Flex is an abstraction layer over some languages, I doubt there is any, unless written in Flex directly. IMO you'd better go pure AS3 and use this class.

Answer (score 2):

LoaderMax- very nice library, which can do lot of things, check here:
http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/

Comment: Yes.I was checking it but i am not sure if it can load reosucres and then give back for later use. Am i wrong ? Seems like it appends as soon as it is done loading.
```queue.append( new ImageLoader("img/photo1.jpg", {name:"photo1", estimatedBytes:2400, container:this, alpha:0, width:250, height:150, scaleMode:"proportionalInside"}) );```

Comment: Yes it can, ex:
    queue.append( new ImageLoader("img/photo1.jpg", {name:"photo1", estimatedBytes:2400, container:this"}) );
and you can use this with this after:
LoaderMax.getContent("photo1");
You just need to name instances to use them later.